# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name when trying to retrieve the entries of a view

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Solved: added new column in VW_MYVIEW (to be used for **id**)

I created a **view** with a script and a **java class** which will have all the columns from the view.
But when I try to get the result list from the view, I receive: **invalid column name exception**.
This is how I what to get the data:

```
 Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from VW_MYVIEW", MyView.class); 

 List<MyView> list = return query.getResultList();
```

Bellow is my view and my java class. I don't have an id in my view so I added:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

because it complains that an id is needed.

```
VW_MYVIEW

COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE
name        | varchar(45)
text        | varchar(20)
nr          | number


@Entity
@Table(name = "VW_MYVIEW")
public class MyView implements Serializable {

  private static final long UID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "text")
  private String text;

  @Column(name = "nr")
  private Long nr;
  
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  public String getText() {
    return text;
  }

  public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  public Long getNr() {
    return nr;
  }

  public void setNr(Long nr) {
    this.nr = nr;
  }
}
```

If you have any ideas why I get that exception please don't hesitate to leave a comment.

Exception:

```
**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3757)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:264)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getLong(GeneratedResultSet.java:558)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:333)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:794)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:719)**
```

Comment: All of the code examples I'm seeing on the Internet require you to enumerate your fields, as in `SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM sometable`.

Comment: I tried, is stii not working :(

Comment: Same error? ....

Comment: Yes. It could be the problem that id that I added in the java class, but i'm not sure..

Comment: OK, I think the error message means exactly what it says.  Check every column name in your MyView class; make sure it lines up precisely with the column names in your SQL and your table.

Comment: I found the problem.. was the id which was missing from my view. So I added a new column in the view for the id (select rownum,.....). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

`type` is [a reserved word in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm).

The best approach would be to rename this column to something that isn't a reserved word. If you cannot do that, you'll need to escape it. E.g.:

```
@Column(name = "\"type\"")
private String type;
```

Comment: Is just a column name used to ask this question here (I don't use a column 'type''), i will modify the column name (I was uninspired) . Sorry..